# Is there a formula for $\sum^{n}_{k=1}\binom{ n-k }{h }k$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I'm trying to show $$\sum ^{400}_{m=1}\binom{ 400-m }{ 3 }m \sim 8.5 \times 10^9\,,$$ but can't seem to find a binomial coefficient identiy.

Comment: Working from the answer and factorising, note that $84269339980 = 2\times 2\times 5\times 7\times 19\times 199\times 397\times 401= {401 \choose 5}$

Comment: [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+%7Bm%5Cchoose+x%7D*%28n-m%29+for+m%3D0..n) gives $\displaystyle \sum\limits_{m=0}^n {m\choose x} (n - m) = \frac{(n^2 - 2 n x + n + (x - 1) x) {n + 1\choose x} + {0\choose x} (n (x + 2) x + x)}{(x + 1) (x + 2)}$

Comment: Apply the Hockey Stick lemma twice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** Apply the Hockey Stick lemma twice.

> $$\sum ^{400}_{m=1} \left[ { 400 -m \choose 3 }  \sum_{i=1}^{m} 1 \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{400} \left[\sum_{m=i}^{400}{ 400-m \choose 3 } \right] = \sum_{i=1}^{400} { i \choose  4 } = { 401 \choose 5 }$$

---

Note: There might be indexing errors as it's late and I'm going to sleep, but you should be able to get the gist.

Yes, this generalizes and can be expressed as an identity.

Comment: nice, I knew the identity but didn't think of that!

Answer (score 1):

Let $a_k = \binom{k}a$ and $b_k=k$. What you want is $c_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k}$. There is a standard way to find this. We have that

$$A(x) = \sum_{k\geqslant a} \binom{k}a x^{k}=x^a\sum_{k\geqslant 0} \binom{k+a}a x^{k}= \frac{x^a}{(1-x)^{a+1}}$$

$$B(x) = \sum_{k\geqslant 0} k x^{k}=\frac x{(1-x)^2} $$

hence

$$C(x) = A(x)B(x) = \frac{x^{a+1}}{(1-x)^{a+3}}=x^{-1}\frac{x^{a+2}}{(1-x)^{a+3}}$$

so the general coefficient of $C$ is...?